# Cut integer into equally sized integers and assign to vector

Tags: r

Lets assume the integer `x`. I want to split this quantity in `n` mostly equal chunks and save the values in a vector. E.g. if `x = 10` and `n = 4` then the resulting vector would be:

```
(3,3,2,2)
```

and if `n = 3`:

```
(4,3,3)
```

Note: The order of the resulting vector does not matter

Comment: Just to follow up on Richard's comment: how to define "mostly equal". Why is (3,3,2,2) preferred over (3,3,3,1)

Comment: I'm sure there is a better option, but crudely you could do: `table(cut(1:x, n, labels=1:n))`

Comment: @user20650: Yes. Cut them in such a way that the maximum deviation from the mean (2.5) is the least. that is (3,3,2,2) (the max deviation being 0.5) is preferred over (3,3,3,1) (the max deviation being 1.5)

Comment: Not sure what caveats are there with an approach like `ans = rep_len(x %/% n, n); i = seq_len(x %% n); ans[i] = ans[i] + 1L; ans`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While this will create a (probably unnecessary) large object when `x` is large, it is still pretty quick:

```
x <- 10
n <- 4
tabulate(cut(1:x, n))
#[1] 3 2 2 3
```

On a decent modern machine dividing 10M records into 100K groups, it takes only 5 seconds:

```
x <- 1e7
n <- 1e5
system.time(tabulate(cut(1:x, n)))
# user  system elapsed 
# 5.07    0.06    5.13
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are some solutions.

**1) lpSolve** Solve this integer linear program.  It should be fast even for large x (but not if n is also large).  I also tried it for x = 10,000 and n = 3 and it returned the solution immediately.

For example, for n = 4 and x = 10 it corresponds to

```
min x4 - x1 such that 0 <= x1 <= x2 <= x3 <= x4 and 
                      x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 = 10 and 
                      x1, x2, x3, x4 are all integer
```

The R code is:

```
library(lpSolve)

x <- 10
n <- 4

D <- diag(n)
mat <- (col(D) - row(D) == 1) - D
mat[n, ] <- 1

obj <- replace(numeric(n), c(1, n), c(-1, 1))
dir <- replace(rep(">=", n), n, "=")
rhs <- replace(numeric(n), n, x)

result <- lp("min", obj, mat, dir, rhs, all.int = TRUE)
result$solution
## [1] 2 2 3 3
```

and if we repeat the above with n = 3 we get:

```
## [1] 3 3 4
```

**2) lpSolveAPI**  The lpSolveAPI package's interface to lpSolve supports a sparse matrix specification which may reduce storage if n is large although it may still be slow if n is sufficiently large.  Rewriting (1) using this package we have:

```
library(lpSolveAPI)

x <- 10
n <- 4

mod <- make.lp(n, n)
set.type(mod, 1:n, "integer")

set.objfn(mod, c(-1, 1), c(1, n))
for(i in 2:n) add.constraint(mod, c(-1, 1), ">=", 0, c(i-1, i))
add.constraint(mod, rep(1, n), "=", x)

solve(mod)    
get.variables(mod)
## [1] 2 2 3 3
```

**3) Greedy Heuristic**  This alternative uses no packages. It starts with a candidate solution having n-1 values of x/n rounded down and one remaining value.  On each iteration it tries to improve the current solution by subtracting one from the largest values and adding 1 to the same number of smallest values.  It stops when it can make no further improvement in the objective, `diff(range(soln))`.

Note that for `x <- 1e7` and `n <- 1e5` it is quite an easy to solve since n divides evenly into x.  In particular `system.time(tabulate(cut(...)))` reports 18 sec on my machine and for the same problem the code below takes 0.06 seconds as it gets the answer after 1 iteration.

For `x <- 1e7` and `n <- 1e5-1` `system.time(tabulate(cut(...)))` reports 16 seconds on my machine and for the same problem the code below takes 4 seconds finishing after 100 iterations.

In the example below, taken from the question, 10/4 rounded down is 2 so it starts out with `c(2, 2, 2, 4)`.  On the first iteration it gets `c(2, 2, 3, 3)`.  On the second iteration it cannot get any improvement and so returns the answer.

```
x <- 10
n <- 4

a <- x %/% n
soln <- replace(rep(a, n), n, x - (n-1)*a)
obj <- diff(range(soln))
iter <- 0
while(TRUE) {
  iter <- iter + 1
  soln_new <- soln
  mx <- which(soln == max(soln))
  ix <- seq_along(mx)
  soln_new[ix] <- soln_new[ix] + 1
  soln_new[mx] <- soln_new[mx] - 1
  soln_new <- sort(soln_new)
  obj_new <- diff(range(soln_new))
  if (obj_new >= obj) break
  soln <- soln_new
  obj <- obj_new
}

iter
## [1] 2
soln
## [1] 2 2 3 3
```

Comment: Will this slow down substantially if you have a large `n`, due to the creation of `diag(n)`? (To answer myself, it doesn't appear so - clearly `diag` isn't as slow as I thought it was. Though it can create a huge object - e.g. `diag(100000)` tries to allocate 74.5Gb)

Comment: I would expect that it would get slow if both x and n were large but if only x were large then it should still be fast.

Comment: Using the `Matrix` package, `bandSparse(n, k = c(0,1), diagonals = list(rep(-1, n), rep(1, n - 1)))` is faster. In addition, since it's a sparse matrix it takes up less memory.

Comment: When `n = 1000` using `bandsparse` is 25 times faster (median execution time with microbenchmark) than `D <- diag(n); mat <- (col(D) - row(D) == 1) - D`.

Comment: @thelatemail Using `bandSparse` to create the matrix when `n = 100000`, even with the last row of `1`s, only takes up 3.8Mb.

Comment: @Ryan - that would be sensible I suppose, given that `diag(n)` is very sparse.

Comment: Actually, maybe my previous comments aren't useful in this context. It seems the `lp` function doesn't like `dgCMatrix` objects.

Comment: Have added additional solutions.  (2) uses lpSolveAPI and its ability to specify the problem using sparsity and in (3) we show a greedy heuristic with some performance measurements.